# How to Register different type user with profile in django?

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I am new to django and I started a new project. 
shortly, I want to register different type of users (Teacher, Student, Stuff) with their profile picture. I made a one to one field from user to profile and below is my code and I get the following error. if you have any suggestion for my registration purpose, I want to register a different type of user with a profile picture.

```
models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,AbstractUser
from django.conf import settings
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class User(AbstractUser):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1,'Student'),
        (2,'Teacher'),
        (3,'Stuff')
    )
    profile = models.OneToOneField(on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user')
    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d/')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Profile {}'.format(self.user.username)
```

its the form

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile

class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label='Password')
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label='Repeat Password')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def clean_password(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password']!=cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('password no match')
        return cd['password2']


class ProfileCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('photo',)
```

its my view module

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ProfileCreationForm, UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile
from django.http import HttpResponse
def sign_up(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserCreationForm(instance=request.user,data=request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileCreationForm(instance=request.user.profile,data=request.POST,
                                           files=request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            new_user.save()
            Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)
            return HttpResponse('user created')

    else:
        user_form = UserCreationForm()
        profile_form = ProfileCreationForm()
    return render(request, '',{'user_form':user_form, 'profile_form':profile_form})
```

here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Mahdi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Mahdi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Mahdi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Mahdi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Mahdi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Mahdi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Mahdi\PycharmProjects\MyProject\accounts\models.py", line 7, in <module>
    class User(AbstractUser):
  File "C:\Users\Mahdi\PycharmProjects\MyProject\accounts\models.py", line 13, in User
    profile = models.OneToOneField(on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user')
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'to'
```

Comment: In your `User` model, you forgot to specify the model to which it should point (here a `Profile`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model you forgot to specify to which model the `OneToOneField` of the `User` model should point (a `Profile`), since that profile is defined later in the Python file, you can not use an identifier, you can however use a string literal that contains the *name* of the model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1,'Student'),
        (2,'Teacher'),
        (3,'Stuff')
    )
    profile = models.OneToOneField('Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user')
    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

You will need to make migrations, and migrate in order to add a table that corresponds to your model in the database.

Since you reference to the `Profile`, that means you will need to first construct a `Profile` before saving the `User` (since otherwise the `profile` will be `NULL`, which is *not* allowed here):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ProfileCreationForm, UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile
from django.http import HttpResponse

def sign_up(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserCreationForm(instance=request.user,data=request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileCreationForm(instance=request.user.profile,data=request.POST,
                                           files=request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            profile = profile_form.save()
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            new_user.profile = profile
            new_user.save()
            return HttpResponse('user created')

    else:
        user_form = UserCreationForm()
        profile_form = ProfileCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'my_template.html',{'user_form':user_form, 'profile_form':profile_form})
```

You also forgot to specify the template. Furthermore it is advicable to return a `redirect(..)` to a view, since otherwise if the user refreshes the browser, a *second* POST request will be made, and this can thus trigger creating *another* user.

Comment: So if i defined the User class and profile that error would'nt occur?

Comment: @user9341824: you defined the models. But in a relation, you need to specify what model you relate to. Here it was missing. So the Django error says: "I do not know to what to relate.

Comment: @user9341824: see the boldface part in the first code fragment.

Comment: Thx I solved it by adding the Profile in the first parameter of the one to one field and then difined an AUTH_USER_MODEL inside settings.py file and made a new migration.

Comment: I know that would cost very much when you are not at the begining of your project.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example 
you should only create a model with a OneToOne to User

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='profile')

    foto = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='usuarios/fotos/',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```